# Mix php array with different key values

Tags: php

Is it possible to merge two arrays (color, application)

```
{
    "red", 
    "green"
}

{
    "1": {
        "4": "11",
        "5": "12"
    },
    "2": {
        "4": "21",
        "5": "22"
    }
}
```

to a new array pushing each value on each value of the first array?

```
{
    "red": {
        "1": {
            "4": "11",
            "5": "12"
        }
    },
    "green" : {
        "2": {
            "4": "21",
            "5": "22"
        }
    }
}
```

The key is different for each array how ever the order will be always correct.

UPDATE: Thanks to @Don'tPanic array_combine() did the work! Thanks

UPDATE2: @arkascha Presented another solution, it happens on my case that both solutions were acceptable, here a screenshot of both results. [link](https://prnt.sc/qy344l)

Comment: It's not possible to get that exact output example because of the duplicate application keys. Can you edit the question to show examples of input/output arrays in actual PHP code or JSON rather than var_dump/print_r format?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I edited the question.

Comment: Okay, cool. I think it looks like a job for [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Comment: e.g. `$output = array_combine($color, $application);`

Comment: @Don'tPanic +1 worked! Thanks!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Comment: Actually it does _not_ work. `array_combine()` delivers something similar, but _not_ the requested result.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible using some magical builtin php function. The requested resulting structure is somewhat "exotic". So try a manual approach, something like that:

```
<?php

$left = [
    "red", 
    "green"
];
$right = [
    "1" => [
        "4" => "11",
        "5" => "12"
    ],
    "2" => [
        "4" => "21",
        "5" => "22"
    ]
];

$out = [];

$rKeys = array_keys($right);
foreach ($left as $key) {
    $out[$key] = [current($rKeys) => $right[current($rKeys)]];
    $val = next($rKeys);
}

print_r($out);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 11
                    [5] => 12
                )

        )

    [green] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 21
                    [5] => 22
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: You're definitely right about array_combine not being able to produce the example result. I did make some assumptions about what was really wanted and what may have been lost in translation when I commented on the question, which I probably should not have done.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Your solutions, also worked for me. At least for this example the output was the same that the one arkascha solution mentioned later.

Comment: @stu Actually no, the outputs differ. You need to look closely, the structure actually _is_ different.

Comment: @arkascha you are right, I took a screenshot of what changed with your solution I will leave it here: https://prnt.sc/qy344l

Comment: That is correct. As said: the results are different. That is because my answer's output resembled _exactly_ what is actually asked in your question, not just roughly, as `array_combine()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @arkascha that array_combine does not quite work for this as I originally commented.

One other option if we need to retain the keys of the application array is to chunk that array before using it as the "values" argument in `array_combine`.

```
$result = array_combine($colors, array_chunk($applications, 1, true));
```